# Nautilus can not resize column ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nautilus

I can't resize columns' width (Name, size, etc.) in Nautilus's 'View items as a list' mode after my upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 (32-bit); while I just had point-and-drag in 13.04 .

Comment: Alas, I get no answer whatsoever. At least someone can tell me, whether they do not have similar problem. In LIST MODE, we CAN NOT resize any column size (Name, Size, Location, etc.), especially when the window in not maximised. Even maximised, resizing IS very difficult. Used to be no problem in earlier version of Ubuntu.

Comment: It is very hard to report to Ubuntu Bug Report nowadays. I just get brought round and round.

Comment: Bug 698017 - default column width calculation is unuseful

Comment: I reported to bugzilla.gnome.org . Apparently this bug has affected a number of people. People that work with List View will notice that. The name column size can not be resized, specially in windows unmaximised condition. Bug id is in my previous comment. In bugzilla, many duplicated report, including mine, which indicates many people are affected.

Comment: ubuntu has so many small bugs that make users migrate to another OS. @Toni Try to remove the column MIME-TYPE from the Files Preferences (List Columns Tab). It does not happen only to 32-bit but 64-bit also. :(